# Tags "slideshows" and "presentations" should be synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-synonyms

We have the tags [slideshows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slideshows) (currently 17 uses) and [presentations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presentations) (currently 22 uses).  As far as I can tell, these are for the very same thing.

I propose merging them.  If you are aware of any reasons why they shouldn't be made synonyms, please post an answer.

Mathematica uses both terms: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PresentationsWithTheWolframSystem.html

Comment: It is hard to tell if https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKaI78K_rgA is a slide show or a presentation?

Comment: If nobody posts any objections by Friday, I'm synonymizing 'em.

Comment: Yeah, synomonkeyze 'em

Answer (score 7):

I made [slideshows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slideshows) the primary tag and synonymized it with [presentations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presentations).

Comment: Thank you, J. M.

Comment: @Kuba, that's why I was asking for any objections in the comments... :P Can you maybe write an answer detailing why you think this should be undone?

Comment: That's an easier request, @Kuba. :)

Comment: @J.M. Thanks :)